# A hard question on surjective group homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abstract-algebra

Say $G$ and $H$ are finite groups, and there exists a surjective group homomorphism from
$G × G$ to $H × H$. Must there exist a surjective group homomorphism from $G$ to $H$? I have no idea how to do this. Help please